# How do I design a form in Word that queries and inserts data from an Excel table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I put together several document submittals per day, and for the coversheet I manually copy/paste from an Excel table into Word for the document list. Also, each coversheet has a header with the submittal info as such:

Project Name
Project Location
Project No.
Submittal No.
Date

Based on these data, I could easily query a spreadsheet and automate the interface... if only I knew how. I remember OpenOffice was good at doing this sort of thing, but that was months ago when I tried it and I cannot find the same functionality in Word. What am I missing?

P.S. I have Access 2010, which may be better for this sort of thing, but I'm not comfortable using it as I am with Excel/Word. Would it be a better idea overall though?

Answer (score 1):

Advanced filter in the Excel data part of the ribbon/menu allows you to setup criteria as you describe.

Comment: This is helpful as a way to pull just the data I need to another table, but it appears I can only copy to another worksheet, NOT to Word. My primary question is how to have these data moved straight into Word without having to copy and paste every time.

Comment: Not trying to force you to do it this way. But you can use the same excel file to pull the relevant list together with advanced filter, or MSQuery, and then have a Word document with that Excel sheet linked into a Word document. and update the link, print, or send, pull data again, update linked sheet. You end up with 2 documents to deal with to accomplish most everything. insert-a-linked-object-or-embedded-object-from-an-excel-file